# How to store a SecretKey within a Java KeyStore protected by a PublicKey (RSAPasswordProtection)?

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I want to store a SecretKey within a Java KeyStore protected by a PublicKey. When loading the protected KeyEntry i would like to

1. get the protected key byte-array to manually unwrap it later on with a PrivateKey.
2. let the KeyStore handle the unwrapping when handing over the PrivateKey.

Using the setEntry()-Method with an already wrapped byte-Array is possible. Also getting the wrapped byte-Array back can be done by using the getEntry()-Method. To encrypt a SecretKey the setEntry()-Method supports the usage of a ProtectionParameter. The only ProtectionParameter i could find was the PasswordProtection parameter.

Does anyone know about a RsaProtection for Java KeyStore? Or is there another way around to be able to wrap SecretKeys using a PublicKey and getting it back using a PrivateKey?

Answer (score 0):

The Java key stores are certainly not able to handle this; they primarily use symmetric encryption to protect the key stores. It is possible to wrap and unwrap keys though. I've shown this using OAEP instead of the less safe `"RSA"` (PKCS#1) encryption:

```
Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
rsa.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
byte[] wrapped = rsa.wrap(aesKey);

rsa.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
SecretKey unwrappedAESKey = (SecretKey) rsa.unwrap(wrapped, "RSA", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
```

Comment: I would think you probably can do it, but you would probably have to write your own `SecretKey`-implementing class. However the keystore will certainly re-encrypt your key with its own passphrase.

Comment: @EJP possibly, but it would require an awful muckin around with the JCA. Of course, if you can sign your own provider you can do anything ;)